# Door problems when creating event system in Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, events

Ok, so I'm just trying to create an event system, when the player goes into the trigger area,
the door is pulled up and when he gets out, the door moves downward. There are 2 doors, each door has an ID to be identified, and each Door's ID corresponds to their Trigger's ID ( ex: if the door's ID is 1, when the trigger triggers, if both ID are equal then the door opens )
 [Illustrating Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/taUH0.png)
**The Problem:**
[Illustrating video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YFWiLePTU_8doMD3qJf97i9U4kIJWNA4/view?usp=sharing)
Explanation: When the player went into the trigger area of door 1, the door pulled up and when he got out the door stopped but what I expected it to do is going down just like door 2. The door 1 and door 2 are nearly the same except that their ID are different. So what is the problem here ?
**Script**
The Event:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Event : MonoBehaviour
{
    public delegate void DoorTrigger(int i);
    public static event DoorTrigger door;
    public static event DoorTrigger undoor;
    public void ExecuteEventDoor(int i)
    {
        door?.Invoke(i);
    }
    public void ExecuteEventUndoor(int i)
    {
        undoor?.Invoke(i);
    }
}
```

Trigger

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Trigger : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int TriggerID = 0;
    public bool firstTime = false;
    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        Debug.Log("door");
        firstTime = true;
        FindObjectOfType<Event>().ExecuteEventDoor(TriggerID);
    }
    private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        Debug.Log("nodoor");
        FindObjectOfType<Event>().ExecuteEventUndoor(TriggerID);    
    }
}
```

And Door:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class DoorMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int ID;
    bool open = false;
    private void OnEnable()
    {
        Event.door += OpenDoor;
        Event.undoor += CloseDoor;
    }
    private void Update()
    {
        if (open)
        {
            transform.Translate(new Vector2(0, 1f * Time.deltaTime));
        }
        else if (!open && FindObjectOfType<Trigger>().firstTime)
        {
            transform.Translate(new Vector2(0, -1f * Time.deltaTime));
        }
    }
    void OpenDoor(int i)
    {
        if (ID == i)
        {
            open = true;
        }
    }
    void CloseDoor(int i)
    {
        if (ID == i)
        {
            open = false;
        }
    }
}
```

**At the first time, the red door had problem but after the player touched the red door ( the second time ), all worked perfectly**

Comment: Not sure of the problem, maybe it's your `TriggerID = 0`? What i would suggest though is this seems really complicated for a simple task, `OnTrigger...` is really all you need, maybe with a extra class to report the event to if you need it. Simple is always better!

Comment: @Absinthe At the first time, the red door had problem but after the player touched the red door ( the second time ), all worked perfectly. Sorry but what do you mean by " maybe with a extra class to report the event to if you need it " ?

Comment: I assumed you're using delegates, events etc as you want some feedback when the player goes through the door, so all I meant was you could have public class, maybe a singleton or static and the scripts on the doors could pass data to that script if you needed it to. Given your comment about it working the second time I'd still guess it's something to do with your ID system, can't test now, sorry.

Comment: Im guessing one of the state booleans does not match the actual state.  Id place my bets on this line `!open && FindObjectOfType<Trigger>().firstTime`, focusing on the `firstTime` boolean.  FindObjectOfType will grab any Trigger from the scene, i doubt that is what you want.  Try to stay away from the `Find` functions.

Comment: @hijinxbassist ye but if i remove the firstTime, the door will automatically move down. Do you have any solution for this ?

Comment: I wasn't saying to remove it.  I believe this is where the issue comes from.  Instead of using `FindObjectOfType<Trigger>()` which will return ANY Trigger it finds in the scene (on this object or not), use a direct reference or (if the Trigger is on this object) use GetComponentInChildren<Trigger>().